# Finding the maximum slope in an Lat\Lon array

Tags: python-3.x, gradient

I'm plotting sea surface height by Latitude for a 20 different Longitudes.
The result is a line plot with 20 lines. I need to find in which line has the steepest slope and then pinpoint that `lat` `lon`.

I've tried so far with np.gradient and then max() but I keep getting an error (ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all())
I have a feeling theres a much better way to do it.Thanks to those willing to help.
 [example of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlkbO.png)

```
slice3lat= lat[20:40] 
slice3lon= lon[20:40] 
slice3ssh=ssh[:,0,20:40,20:40]

plt.plot(slice3lat,slice3ssh)
plt.xlabel("Latitude")
plt.ylabel("SSH (m)")
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Helo, can you share what have you tried?

Comment: Ive tried using np.gradient and then max() but it returns an error each time,

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You should all that info (errors, your code, example data) incorporate in your question. It will help other users to answer your question.

Comment: Ok thanks, Im new here

Comment: Great to have you here. I'm just trying to help you create question that will be interested for someone fluent in python to help you. I'm not best qualified for that, but I know that better documented question is more interesting for other users ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `max()`, I assume you mean Python's built-in `max` function. This works on `numpy` arrays only if they are one-dimensional / flat, where by iterating over the elements, size comparable scalars are obtained. If you have a 2D array like in your case, the top-level elements of the array become its rows, where the size comparison fails with the message you presented.

In this case, you should use `np.max` on the array or call the `arr.max()` method directly.

Here's some example code using `np.gradient`, vector adding the gradients in each direction and obtaining the max together with its coordinate position in the original data:

```
grad_y, grad_x = np.gradient(ssh)
grad_total = np.sqrt(grad_y**2 + grad_x**2)  #  or just grad_y ?

max_grad = grad_total.max()
max_grad_pos = np.unravel_index(grad_total.argmax(), grad_total.shape)

print("Gradient max is {} at pos {}.".format(max_grad, max_grad_pos))
```

Might ofc still need to fiddle a liddle with it.

Comment: This is awesome, and it works as is, just a couple of questions. Where you put the max_grad_pos is it possible to return the lat lon coordinates of max_grad? And does this function take in to account both the meridional and zonal gradients? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add some example data for `ssh` to your OP? I can't really say without knowing what it looks like. Then the gradients might need to be adapted, this example was only for 2D, but the lat/lon coordinates should be in there, yes.

Comment: SSH has 4 layers, [time, depth, lat, lon]. Its from a NetCDF file. What I'm doing is defining a small area in the entire grid and looking for the max gradient in that area. I then would like to get as an output the latitude and longitude of the max gradient. Does this help?

Comment: For example I define slice1=ssh[ : , 0 , 20:40 , 20:40 ]. Can I use the output from max_grad_pos as an index in lat\lon?

Comment: OK I found a way, I just took the position outputs separately and used them to find their value in the Lat\Lon arrays. Thanks